# insert key=>value pair in PHP from a submitted Javascript object

Tags: javascript, php

im trying to figure out how to properly insert `key=>value` pair to an array using `array_unshift`

this is my code.

Javascript/AJAX

```
var array= {};
array['name'] = name;
array['lname'] = lname;

$.ajax ({ 
   type:"POST",
   url:"some.php",
   data: {array:array},
   success: function(html) {}
});
```

PHP will then receive the array via POST

```
$array = $_post['array'];

//add additional key=>value pair in the array
array_unshift($array, "['middle']=>test");
return $array;
```

Im not getting any errors from it, i just dont see the value being printed from the function.

Printed Result:

```
Object {name: "John", lname: "Smith"}
```

edit:typo

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're doing it right...

You can't alter a JavaScript array (it's an object actually) via PHP. However, you **can** fetch new data and replace the JavaScript object.

Because I'm expecting an object, I might as well use the JSON format - thus use `$.getJSON()` instead. Note that this is a GET request on default.

```
var url = 'file.php';
var obj = {
    name: name,
    lname: lname
};

$.getJSON(url, { data:obj }, function(data) {
    // replace object with new content
    obj = data;
    console.log(obj);
});
```

As for your PHP code:

```
// get data (remember we're using a GET request)
$data = $_GET['data'];

// add an index
$data['middle'] = 'test';

// echo data in JSON format
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Also, it should be `$array = $_POST['array'];` instead of `$array = $_post['array'];`

Answer (score 0):

Rename the `person` to `array` like

```
var array= {};
array['name'] = name;
array['lname'] = lname;

$.ajax ({ 
   type:"POST",
   url:"some.php",
   data: {array:array},
   success: function(html) {}
});
```

Or send the `person` array as `array`

```
data: {array:person},
```

**EDIT :**.Simple try like

```
$array['middle'] = 'test';
```

Comment: hi sorry, that was a typo.i meant it to be `array['name']` but still, i dont see this part `array_unshift($array, "['middle']=>test");` being added.

Comment: it didn't worked for me. i just get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
// not var array= {};
var person = {}
person['name'] = name;
person['lname'] = lname;
```